# Non-loading PrimeFaces component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, primefaces

I am a JavaEE/JSF beginner and want to load PrimeFaces components in a Dashboard/Bootstrap theme available for free : http://www.creative-tim.com/product/light-bootstrap-dashboard

Some are loading (buttons), some are not (charts, for example). I want to load animated charts : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/animate.xhtml (this example in fact)

The component is fully loading on a blank page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <p:chart type="line" model="#{chartView.animatedModel1}" style="width:400px;" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

However, it's not loading with the full design :

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card">
             <p:chart type="line" model="#{chartView.animatedModel1}" style="width:400px;" />
         </div>
      </div>

     <div class="col-md-8">
         <div class="card">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And here is the CSS for "card" :

```
.card {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0 0 1px rgba(63, 63, 68, 0.1);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.card .image {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 260px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.card .image img {
  width: 100%;
}
.card .filter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.card .filter .btn {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.card:hover .filter {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.card .btn-hover {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.card:hover .btn-hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.card .content {
  padding: 15px 15px 10px 15px;
}
.card .header {
  padding: 15px 15px 0;
}
.card .category,
.card label {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #9A9A9A;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.card .category i,
.card label i {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.card label {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.card .title {
  margin: 0;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.card .avatar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.card .description {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
.card .footer {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.card .footer .legend {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.card .footer hr {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.card .stats {
  color: #a9a9a9;
}
.card .footer div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.card .author {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.card .author i {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.card h6 {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}
.card.card-separator:after {
  height: 100%;
  right: -15px;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}
.card .ct-chart {
  margin: 30px 0 30px;
  height: 245px;
}
.card .table tbody td:first-child,
.card .table thead th:first-child {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.card .table tbody td:last-child,
.card .table thead th:last-child {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.card .alert {
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}
.card .alert.alert-with-icon {
  padding-left: 65px;
}
```

I really can't see why the Javascript generated can't execute (or maybe it is hidden by the design ?), does anyone have any idea or does this recquires additional details ? Thanks

**EDIT :** Jonathan Crégut nailed it !

Comment: Start stripping your css…  one line at a time and see when it becomes visible

Comment: Next time press F12 in webbrowser for clues.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is no loading of jQuery somewhere else in your template. Primefaces also loads its version of jQuery and it usually ends up showing nothing.